# How to access Json Object which has an @ sign in it as an object name?

Tags: javascript, json

Ladies and Gentlemen,

Using javascript, how do I access 'id' in a JSON string that looks like this:

```
 "graph": {
     "edges": {
        "edge": [
            {
                "@": {
                    "id": "3825279",
                    "label": "succeeds",
                    "source": "2746694",
                    "target": "2746515"
                },
```

I am able to get edge, but I get stopped dead cold by the "@" sign:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(json.graph.edges.edge[0]));
```

which returns:

> "@": {
>                       "id": "3825279",
>                       "label": "succeeds",
>                       "source": "2746694",
>                       "target": "2746515"
>                   },

How do I access id in this object?  I have tried:

```
json.graph.edges.edge[0].edge // undefined
```

The @ sign is an Object representing all attributes on the specified tag, but how do I use it?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
json.graph.edges.edge[0]['@']
```

?

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript,  `o.a` and `o["a"]` are completely equivalent, so this will work:

```
json.graph.edges.edge[0]["@"]
```